# How to read stdin for particular strings and perform Boolean operations on them?

Tags: c

I'm attempting to read in a text file from stdin of the form

```
12  1 $2
30  3 $9
1   1 $5  asdf
0  23 $3
0   alpha
1   beta
2   gamma
3   delta
```

I would like for the first conditional statement to check the range values and see if there are occurrences of "alpha", "beta", "gamma" and "delta". If one of those strings is absent, then I want to use exit(1).

I'm not too sure how to exactly store those strings in memory or search for them from stdin. 
Any guidance is appreciated.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
int x;
int y;
char type[3];

while(1){
  if(scanf("%d %d %s%*[^\n]%*c", &x, &y, type)!=3)break;
  if(x>30 || y>30 || x<0 || y<0)||!("alpha" && "beta"
&& "gamma" && "delta"))
// The above syntax is wrong, but I think it shows what I'm thinking.
// If one of those strings are not found, exit(1).      
{
    exit(1);
    }
  if(x==0 || y==0){
    goto X;
  }
//Do stuff
}
X:if((x==0 || y==0)==1){

//Do stuff
return(0);
}

}//end main
```

Comment: Have you heard about `break`? Well, you have, I see you are using it. Then why `goto`?

Comment: What's this: `!("alpha" && "beta"
&& "gamma" && "delta")`?? It will always evaluate to `false`. you really need a good `C` book.

Comment: [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) allows you to get a string. To test if they are what you want, try [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: Also, avoid using goto. It is horrible!

Comment: As @LeonardoAlvesMachado use `fgets` to read the text but use `strstr` to check for the substring occurrence

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado: `goto` is entirely permissible in C. `goto` with a non-descriptive single character label that differs from a local variable only by capitalization is certainly not.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    int x;
    int y;
    char type[3];
    char kinds[16];
    int alpha, beta, gamma, delta;//flags
    int status;

    alpha = beta = gamma = delta = 0;
    while(1){
        if((status = scanf("%d %d %2s", &x, &y, type)) == 3){
            if(x > 30 || y > 30 || x < 0 || y < 0)
                exit(1);
            //valid data1
            //do stuff 
            puts("valid data1");//debug print
        } else if(status == 1){
            if(1 == scanf("%15s", kinds)){
                if(strcmp(kinds, "alpha")==0) alpha = 1;
                else if(strcmp(kinds, "beta")==0) beta = 1;
                else if(strcmp(kinds, "gamma")==0) gamma = 1;
                else if(strcmp(kinds, "delta")==0) delta = 1;
                //else /* unknown kind*/ ;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");//clear upto end of line
    }
    if(!(alpha && beta && gamma && delta)){
        exit(1);
    }
    //valid data2
    //do stuff
    puts("valid data2");//debug print

    return 0;
}
```